# Is it professional to attend a christmas dinner after leaving the company?

Tags: professionalism, resignation

I just told my boss (last week) that I will be leaving the company on the 23rd. We are still in good relation.

He just invited every employee (including me) to a christmas diner on the 30th.

**Is it professional to attend a christmas dinner after leaving the company?**

Comment: Do you have a reason not to go?

Comment: Confirm with your boss that you're invited, then decide. Voting to close because you are asking what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly acceptable to attend the Christmas party - your boss wouldn't have invited you if that was the case.

Now, if you would feel uncomfortable going to the party (though you haven't given us any reason to think you should), it's fine to say no as well. Just make up some benign excuse for why you can't make it (e.g. you have already made plans with friends/family that evening). This is easier when the party is in the evening. If it's a lunch party you could make up a doctor's appointment. But really I'd say just tough it out and go; it will only be a couple hours of your life.

Comment: The boss could have sent the invitation to a mailing list, for example, a list of employees reporting to him, without intending to invite the OP per se. It would be best for OP to confirm with his boss, rather than just showing up for the party and becoming the topic of "talk behind the back".